# XBox 360 has no sound with HDMI cable

Tags: monitor, xbox-360

I received an xbox for Christmas and I've been trying to connect it. Unfortunately, when I connect it using an HDMI cable, I get picture but no sound. I've made sure my TV is set to "TV Speaker" (it's a Samsung Plasma), but with no luck. I've made sure that my volume is un-muted and turned up in order to hear the game, but no sound seems to be coming from the TV.

I also tried to connect the A/V cords in the back of the xbox so that I can route sound to my receiver, thinking that perhaps the HDMI connection on the xbox doesn't support audio, but it seems that when you connect the A/V cable (i.e. the RCA convertor) to the back of the xbox, it makes i

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to find an answer to this question [here](http://forums.xbox-scene.com/index.php?showtopic=631109). Basically, the HDMI handshake doesn't work correctly between some TVs and the Xbox. The TV tells the Xbox to only allow PC-like display options if it's set to auto-detect the display settings.

To fix this:

1. Open the options on the Xbox Main Screen
2. Right until you get to `Settings`
3. Select `Console Settings` → `Display Discovery`
4. Turn the `auto display discovery` to *Off*

It will ask you to reset your TV and Xbox, after which you should have sound.
You will also need to reset your display configuration (i.e. your resolution/HD settings).

Comment: I was in the opposite situation: I wanted HDMI for video, but wanted to use the audio cable from the a/v connector. You can use both, but in some models, you need to remove the plastic outer case from the connector to allow clearance for the hdmi cable,